# How to use curl command in ansible playbook

Tags: curl, ansible

I have to write same syntax in playook as given in this curl -
curl -Is "{{url}}" -H "Cookie: ROUTEID=8d1617097a0a51a9e361709ad3f5254b; isBannerTester=1"|grep -iE 'Set-Cookie:|Location'

I have to write same syntax in playook as given in this curl -
curl -Is "{{url}}" -H "Cookie: ROUTEID=8d1617097a0a51a9e361709ad3f5254b; isBannerTester=1"|grep -iE 'Set-Cookie:|Location'

```
- name: "sanity"
  shell: curl -Is "https://{{ENV_DOMAIN}}/applicationNavigator/" -H "Cookie: ROUTEID=8d1617097a0a51a9e361709ad3f5254b; isBannerTester=1"|grep -iE
  args:
     warn: no
  register: res
- debug:
    var: res
```

ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to be in '/mnt/banner/deploy/ansible/sanity_test_update.yml': line 40, column 84, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
    - name: "sanity"
      shell: curl -Is "https://studentconnect.acu.edu.au/BannerAdmin.ws/" -H "Cookie: ROUTEID=8d1617097a0a51a9e361709ad3f5254b; isBannerTester=1"|grep -iE
                                                                                   ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
unbalanced quotes. If starting a value with a quote, make sure the
line ends with the same set of quotes. For instance this arbitrary
example:

    foo: "bad" "wolf"

Could be written as:

    foo: '"bad" "wolf"'
```

Comment: If I run cURL command [curl -Is "https://studentconnect.acu.edu.au/BannerAdmin.ws/" -H "Cookie: ROUTEID=8d1617097a0a51a9e361709ad3f5254b; isBannerTester=1"|grep -iE 'Set-Cookie:|Location'] from  local command prompt its giving result like this-  curl -Is "https://studentconnect.acu.edu.au/BannerAdmin.ws/" -H "Cookie: ROUTEID=8d1617097a0a51a9e361709ad3f5254b; isBannerTester=1"|grep -iE 'Set-Cookie:|Location'  same I try with in playbook with -command: curl -Is "https://studentconnect.acu.edu.au/BannerAdmin.ws/" -H "Cookie:ROUTEID=8d1617097a0a51a9e361709ad3f5254b; isBannerTester=1 its nt working

Comment: getting below error- fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["curl", "-Is", "https://studentconnect.acu.edu.au/BannerAdmin.ws/", "-H", "Cookie:ROUTEID=8d1617097a
0a51a9e361709ad3f5254b; isBannerTester=1"], "delta": "0:00:21.349820", "end": "2019-06-11 19:49:15.116093", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 7, "start":
"2019-06-11 19:48:53.766273", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

Comment: Seems my script is working now but sometimes it gives error and sometimes it works, I suspect its timeout issue. Can anyone help to get syntax for time out, below  is my script---  tasks:
   - name: cURL command
     shell: curl -Is "https://studentconnect.acu.edu.au/BannerAdmin.ws/" -H "Cookie:ROUTEID=8d1617097a0a51a9e361709ad3f5254b; isBannerTester=1"
     args:
        warn: no
     register: res
   - debug:
        var: res.stdout_lines

Answer (score 1):

Try the uri module in ansible.

```
- name: curlcommand
  uri:
    url: https://studentconnect.acu.edu.au/BannerAdmin.ws/
    headers:
      Cookie: ROUTEID=8d1617097a0a51a9e361709ad3f5254b
      isBannerTester=1
```

You can even check for specific status codes by giving **status code: 200** or whatever code you want.

Comment: - name: curlcommand
  uri:
    url: https://studentconnect.acu.edu.au/BannerAdmin.ws/
    headers:
      Cookie: ROUTEID=8d1617097a0a51a9e361709ad3f5254b
            
      #this worked, in place of header, body keyword is also worked like below:
      
       - name: curlcommand
  uri:
    url: https://studentconnect.acu.edu.au/BannerAdmin.ws/
    body:
      Cookie: ROUTEID=8d1617097a0a51a9e361709ad3f5254b

Answer (score 0):

Try what's suggested `foo: '"bad" "wolf"'`. Quotation should be escaped, I think.

```
shell: 'curl -Is \"https://{{ENV_DOMAIN}}/applicationNavigator/\"
             -H \"Cookie: ROUTEID=8d1617097a0a51a9e361709ad3f5254b; isBannerTester=1\"|
        grep -iE'
```

Comment: It would be better to put these comments into the question. You're able to edit and update the question.